# Don't know how to get reports that group differently to total the same

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 2 reports needing to list the same amount as they group differently and both require the amount to be rounded to the tenth place.

Example:  October data

```
County Tons Date
```

AB  2.48 10/01/09
 AB  2.25 10/15/09
 AB  2.34    10/15/09
 BC  2.76 10/02/09
 BC  2.85 10/03/09
 BC  4.74 10/03/09

a.  Monthly report - Example (October)

County  Tons(Rounded to the tenth place)
 AB   7.1
 BC  10.4
            ____
   17.5

The Monthly reports are grouped and summarized by county
Formula:  ROUND(SUM({@Tons},{COUNTY.ID}), 1)

---

b.  Quarterly report - Example

Month  Tons(Rounded to the tenth place)
 October  17.4
 November 22.3
 November 14.5
                ____
       54.2

The Quarterly reports are grouped and summarized by date
Formula:    ROUND(SUM({@Tons}, {RECORD.DATE},"monthly"), 1)

Answer (score 0):

Try not doing any rounding in your formulas.  Use the formatting options to show only 1 decimal point when displaying the tonnage.  That way your formulas will always be working with the most accurate (non rounded) data.